# Sort Model by a nested Relationship count

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Room Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Room extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the comments for the room.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

Comment Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{

    /**
     * Get the room that owns the comment.
     */
    public function room()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Room');
    }

    public function upvotes() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Upvote');
    }
}
```

Upvote Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Upvote extends Model
{

    /**
     * Get the comment that the upvote belongs to.
     */    
    public function comment() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

How would I be able to have a list of comments for the room that is sorted by the count of upvotes each comment has?

I have searched online and have only managed to find answers relating to having the model sorted by its directed relation e.g `$room->comments()` rather than being sorted by `$room->comments()->upvotes()`?

Thanks

Comment: is upvotes just a counter of how many "likes" a comment has? if so, couldn't you just add it as a field on the `comments` table, and sort by that?

Comment: Upvotes needs to be a model so that I can manipulate it in ways I wouldn't be able to with just an incremental field, for example removing a banned users Upvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method which will calculate number of upvotes for each comment and will create `upvotes_count` property:

```
 Comment::where('room_id', $roomId)
        ->withCount('upvotes')
        ->orderBy('upvotes_count', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: This looks promising thank you. How would I use this where I am receiving the Room model through Route Model Binding and accessing the comments via `$room->comments()`?

Comment: @HarryNewsome I'd still use this code, just change `$roomId` to real variable.

Comment: I see, I'll remove Comments from being loaded automatically and give the above a try. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with a join and a raw query:

```
$comments = \App\Comment::join('upvotes', function($j) {
            $j->on('upvotes.comment_id', '=', 'comments.id');
        })
        ->where('comments.room_id', $roomId)
        ->with('upvotes')
        ->groupBy('comments.id')
        ->orderBy('count', 'desc')
        ->select((['comments.*', \DB::raw('COUNT(upvotes.comment_id) as count')]))->get();
```